# Working with SObjects instead of concrete custom objects (i.e., abstraction in apex)

Tags: apex, custom-object, sobject, dynamic-apex, canonical-qa

We have a bunch of custom objects, some of which implement a specific set of custom fields of the same type. (e.g., UniqueID, ExternalID, etc.). I want to be able to write one method that takes and object and works with these fields without knowing (or caring) which object type it is. I know it is easily doable in Java but not sure how Apex allows this.
So I want something like this:

```
public static void updateID(SObject myObject){
    myObject.uniqueID__c = myObject.externalID__c;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Mechanics

You need to use the `get` and `put` methods. Each method supports both `String` and `SObjectField` as the parameter type:

```
// terse
myObject.put('UniqueId__c', myObject.get('ExternalId__c'));

// verbose
SObjectField fieldToGet = MyObject__c.ExternalId__c;
SObjectField fieldToPut = MyObject__c.UniqueId__c;
Object value = myObject.get(fieldToGet);
myObject.put(fieldToPut, value);
```

---

## Best Practice

There are many different scenarios under which you may want to use the dynamic methods `get` and `put`. How do you decide whether to use `String` or `SObjectField`?

### SObjectField

**Pros**

- Creates a hard-coded reference to the field.
- If you try to delete the referenced field or change its API Name, the UI will prevent you from doing so!

  - In other words, this approach *protects your code*.

**Cons**

- Syntax is somewhat more verbose. If you are really crunching up against the character limit, this style of reference might use more than you need.

  - There are probably better ways to shave characters.
- You cannot pass cross-object references, like if you wanted to reference `Account.Owner.Name` from `Opportunity`.

  - You cannot call `someOpportunity.get('Account.Owner.Name')`, but you can combine `getSObject` and some string parsing to achieve the desired result.

### String

**Pros**

- More terse syntax allows you to write the same code in fewer characters.
- Accepting this type as an input for your own method would allow you to support cross-object `get` calls (by incorporating `getSObject`).

**Cons**

- Does not populate to the SymbolTable, meaning there is no programmatic connection anywhere between your code and the referenced field.
- Because there is no programmatic connection, the system. will allow the field to be deleted or renamed (barring other blocking dependencies).

  - In other words, your code is *vulnerable* to configuration changes which might break it down the road.

---

## Documentation

Both of the above are well covered in the `Apex Developer Guide` documentation for the **[`SObject`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)** class. There are a few more signatures but you get the idea:

> **get(fieldName)**
>   Returns the value for the field specified by fieldName, such as AccountNumber.
>
> **Signature**
>
> ```
>  public Object get(String fieldName)
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *fieldName*
>   Type: [String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_methods_system_string)
>
> **Return Value**
>   Type: Object
>
> **Usage**
>   For more information, see [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).
>
> ---
>
> **put(fieldName, value)**
>   Sets the value for the field specified by the field token Schema.sObjectField, such as, Schema.Account.AccountNumber and returns the previous value for the field.
>
> **Signature**
>
> ```
> public Object put(Schema.SObjectField fieldName, Object value)
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *fieldName*
>   Type: [Schema.SObjectField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm#apex_class_Schema_SObjectField)
>
> *value*
>   Type: Object
>
> **Return Value**
>   Type: Object

Comment: The field token form should be preferred, because it prevents accidents from happening (e.g. renaming a field, misspelling a field, etc).

Comment: @sfdcfox Depends what you're trying to support. If you want to support cross-object, you don't have a choice.

Comment: Yep. Just saying that one should prefer the object version when possible. I've seen far too many cases where developers went straight to using strings for everything, only to have one minor change by an unwitting admin break things.